# SQL query that states- Pull the minimum date where owner contains %WF%

Tags: sql

I am working on a query where I am trying to pull the minimum date where the owner contains WF in the table.

Table is similar to below:

```
Order Number
Create Date
Modified Date
Owner
```

for every order, I need to pull where the minimum modified date where the owner contains %WF%.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Here is the query that I have:

```
select distinct (ol.order_no),
min(os.assgn_dt) as MinDate,
ow.owner_desc, 
ol.created_Date,
md.media_type_desc,
ow.owner_desc,
st.status_type_Desc,
os.comment,
tt.team_type_desc,
br.sdescrip as Branch,
ol.bgrp_cnt


from order_log ol
join activity_type att on ol.activity_type_id = att.activity_type_id
join branches br on ol.branch = br.lbranch
join regions rg on br.lregion = rg.lregion
join businessunit bu on rg.lbusinessunit = bu.lbusinessunit
join vwCurrentStatus vcs on vcs.order_no = ol.order_no
join order_status os on os.order_no = vcs.order_no
join owner ow on os.owner_name = ow.owner_id
join status_type st on st.status_type_id = os.status_type_id
join team_type tt on ow.team_type_id = tt.team_type_id
join media_type md on ol.media_type_id = md.media_type_id
join rep_name_xref rnx on rnx.order_no = ol.order_no
join rep_names rn on rn.user_id = rnx.user_id

where ow.owner_desc like '%WF%' 
and ol.created_date > '01-01-2012'
and att.activity_type_id in ('14','16')
and tt.team_type_desc in ('1-10 Membership Team','government')

group by ol.order_no, ow.owner_desc, ol.created_Date,md.media_type_desc,ow.owner_desc,st.status_type_Desc,     os.comment, tt.team_type_desc,br.sdescrip, ol.bgrp_cnt
```

Comment: Do you mean that you can have the same value for `Order` with different dates?

Comment: Do you want a minimum date figure for each matching order, or a single minimum date for all the matching orders?

Comment: I want a minimum date figure for each matching order. but each order can have multiple owners with WF... I just need the first one with the minimum date.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
select order_number,min(modified_date) from orders where owner like '%WF%' group by order_number;
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding what you said in the comments, try this:

```
SELECT t.Owner, t.ModifiedDate
FROM tablename t
WHERE t.ModifiedDate = (SELECT MIN(t2.ModifiedDate)
                      FROM tablename t2
                      WHERE t2.Owner like '%WF%')
```

It will give you the list of `Owners` that have the `ModifiedDate equal to` the `Min(ModifiedDate)` from a `Owner` with `'%WF%'`.

Comment: I tried both query above, however, it is giving me two dates... in the results, you can have many owners with the %WF% but only want the ones to return with the MIN dates that has the first WF owner. I can try to post query I have to help.

Comment: maybe now it gives what you want? If not, put on your question values from the table and what you expect as a result.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the minimum order date for all orders where the owner contains 'WF', try:

```
SELECT MIN(ModifiedDate)
FROM MyTable
WHERE Owner like '%WF%'
```